# HWIOAuthBundle Symfony2 facebook login route name

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

Where do I find the route name for logging in with facebook? I don't want to hardcode the routes into the twig templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Route name is `hwi_oauth_service_redirect`:

```
Name                                Method   Scheme Host Path
hwi_oauth_service_redirect          ANY      ANY    ANY  /connect/{service}
```

So, for **facebook** you can generate connect route in view via:

```
{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', { service: 'facebook' }) }}
```

### How to debug similar problems

I was also amazed how HWIOAuthBundle doesn't mention route name in documentation anywhere, or at least it isn't obviously stated and I couldn't find it.

When you have this kind of problem, you can use `$ app/console router:debug` command, which will provide you dump of all routes defined.